# Calculating degree of abduction from pitch reading

Tags: geometry

I'm trying to determine the abduction of a person's arm from a wearable pitch sensor, so the minimum pitch reading when the arm is relaxed at the person's side, outputs a value of `7` when the arm is fully abducted above the head a reading is `2`.

My aim of the calculation in the program is to convert these readings to degrees of abduction from resting to fully extended over head.

So a pitch reading of `2` should display 180 degrees while `7` the resting position should read zero degrees.

As a side note, I'm new to this forum, so please correct me if there are any improvments to be made to this question.

I'm not sure what the flaw is in my calculation, any ideas?

```
               //constants
               private int PITCH_MAX_READING = 2;
               private int PITCH_MIN_READING = 7;

               //callibration factor calculated by subtracting the max reading from
               //the min reading, then dividing that result into 180.
               private int CALLIBRATION_FACTOR = 36;   //180/5 = 36

               //Integer variable that holds final degree output
               int degreeOutput;

               const float PI = (float)System.Math.PI;

               //pitch output in 0-9 values
               pitch = (int)((e.Pitch + PI) / (PI * 2.0f) * 10);


               myoCorrected = pitch - PITCH_MIN;

               degreeOutput = myoCorrected * CALLIBRATION_FACTOR;

               //flaw in output as bottom of movement shows 360 degrees, should
               //be zero, although the correct degree output of 180 is displayed
               //for the top of the movement, ie arm extended above head vertically.
               degreeOutput = degreeOutput - 180;



               degreeOfAbductionTbx.Text = "Degree: " + degreeOutput;
```

The calculation I'm using at the moment shows 180 degrees at the top of the movement, ie pitch reading `2` but when the arm is lowered back to the resting position, ie, `7` it shows a reading of 360 degrees but it should be zero degrees.

[image: shoulder abduction]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a method that does the conversion from pitch to degrees for you.

```
public int convertAbductionToDegrees(int abductionPitch) {

    int DEGREE_ABDUCTION_RATIO = 36;
    int MAX_PITCH = 252;



    return MAX_PITCH - (abductionPitch * DEGREE_ABDUCTION_RATIO);

}
```

Comment: Thanks, Kylar are you available tomorrow to discuss the new problem I'm facing regarding the raw pitch values?